# Rails 5.0.0.beta1, two database setup creates additional active_record_internal_metadatas tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to implement a two database setup in `rails 5.0.0.beta1`. Everything seems to be working quite fine but I've run into something odd. The models connect to the specified databases, associations work, migrations (after some tweaks) work fine too. After I run the migrations an additional table, called `active_record_internal_metadatas`, appears in both databases. When I tested this setup on `rails 4.2.5` there were no such thing. Can somebody shed some light on the issue?

The settings for a double database setup:

- `database.yml`

  ```
  default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

  development:
    <<: *default
    database: app_name_development_first

  development_second:
    <<: *default
    database: app_name_development_second
  ```
- `second_db_connection.rb` - a model which handles the connection to the second database. All models that are supposed to be in the second database have to inherit from this model.

  ```
  class SecondDbConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
      establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_second".to_sym
      self.abstract_class = true
  end
  ```
- `application_controller.rb` - caching connections for the second database

  ```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    around_filter :cache_other_db_connections

    private
      def cache_other_db_connections
        SecondDbConnection.connection.cache { yield }
      end
  end
  ```
- `db.rake` - overwritten migration tasks

  ```
  namespace :db do
    task :migrate do
      Rake::Task['db:migrate_first'].invoke
      Rake::Task['db:migrate_second'].invoke
    end

    task :migrate_first do
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ("#{Rails.env}".to_sym)
      ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate('db/db_first/migrate/')
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
    end

    task :migrate_second do
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ("#{Rails.env}_second".to_sym)
      ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate('db/db_second/migrate/')
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
    end
  end
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a Rails 5 feature. Here is an quotation from [this pull request commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/900bfd94a9c3c45484d88aa69071b7a52c5b04b4#diff-08a3e7333b5c1a6b357298070b7b6002) introducing it:

> **Prevent destructive action on production database**
>
> This PR introduces a
>   key/value type store to Active Record that can be used for storing
>   internal values. It is an alternative implementation to #21237 cc
>   @sgrif @matthewd.
>
> It is possible to run your tests against your production database by
>   accident right now. While infrequently, but as an anecdotal data
>   point, Heroku receives a non-trivial number of requests for a database
>   restore due to this happening. In these cases the loss can be large.
>
> To prevent against running tests against production we can store the
>   "environment" version that was used when migrating the database in a
>   new internal table. Before executing tests we can see if the database
>   is a listed in `protected_environments` and abort. There is a manual
>   escape valve to force this check from happening with environment
>   variable `DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this PR didn't come up while I was googling it :)